# Access SQL: subquery into IIF?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subquery

I have the following query that works fine:

```sql
SELECT NomComplet, IIF(Count(FS3.Index) = 0, '0 (RAS)', Count(FS3.Index))  
 FROM ControleAcces INNER JOIN ( 
     Employes LEFT JOIN ( 
         SELECT FS1.Index, FS1.OTP, FS1.OTP, FS1.Axe, FS1.FaitSaillant, FS1.Utilisateur, FS2.DateInsertion  
         FROM FaitsSaillants AS FS1 INNER JOIN ( 
             SELECT Axe, Index, Max(FaitsSaillants.DateInsertion) AS DateInsertion  
             FROM FaitsSaillants  
             WHERE DateValue(DateInsertion) > #2010-01-01#  
             AND DateValue(DateInsertion) < #2011-12-31#  
             GROUP BY Axe, Index 
         ) AS FS2  
         ON (FS1.DateInsertion = FS2.DateInsertion  
         AND FS1.Index = FS2.Index)  
         WHERE FS1.Axe = 'Project' AND FS2.Axe = 'Project' 
     ) AS FS3  
     ON Employes.CIP = FS3.Utilisateur 
 )  
 ON ControleAcces.Valeur = Employes.CIP
 GROUP BY NomComplet
 ORDER BY NomComplet
```

Don't bother to fully understand it, all I want it to edit my IIF condition on the first line. Actually, the condition doesn't do much, it checks how many FS3.Index the query returns and concatenate `(RAS)` if it's 0. However, in fact, I would like it to check if there is any row in `FaitsSaillants` where `Axe = 'RAS'`. If the Count() of this is > 0, then the condition is met.

Can I do a subquery into the IIF segment, something like `SELECT COUNT(Index) FROM FaitsSaillants WHERE Axe = 'RAS' AND Utilisateur = FS1.Utilisateur`? If the result is 0, then I add the `RAS` to my second field's results. If not, it stays `Count(FS3.Index)`.

I tried it and while the syntax is correct, the problem is it can't check for the `Utilisateur = FS1.Utilisateur` condition because FS1 is in the main query. However, I must check this because this is the only way to be sure that I'm looking for the right thing: it must be the same `Utilisateur` whether I'm in the main query or the subquery.

**EDIT:**

Here is a shorter version of what I tried from the answers/comments below.

```sql
SELECT NomComplet, IIf(FS2.AxeCount > 0, "0 (RAS)", count(FS3.index))
FROM ControleAcces INNER JOIN (Employes LEFT JOIN (SELECT FS2.AxeCount, FS1.Index, FS1.OTP, FS1.OTP, FS1.Axe, FS1.FaitSaillant, FS1.Utilisateur, FS2.DateInsertion  
         FROM FaitsSaillants AS FS1 INNER JOIN ( 
             SELECT Axe, Index, Max(FaitsSaillants.DateInsertion) AS DateInsertion, SUM(IIf(Axe = 'RAS', 1, 0)) As AxeCount  
             FROM FaitsSaillants 
             GROUP BY Axe, Index 
         ) AS FS2  
         ON (FS1.DateInsertion = FS2.DateInsertion  
         AND FS1.Index = FS2.Index)  
     )  AS FS3 ON Employes.CIP = FS3.Utilisateur) ON ControleAcces.Valeur = Employes.CIP
GROUP BY NomComplet;
```

I still got an error about FS2.AxeCount that isn't a part of the aggregate function (iff).

I've also tried this:

```sql
SELECT NomComplet, IIf((select count(*) from FaitsSaillants where axe='RAS' and Utilisateur=ControleAcces.Valeur) > 0, "0 (RAS)", count(FS3.index))
FROM ControleAcces INNER JOIN (Employes LEFT JOIN (SELECT FS2.AxeCount, FS1.Index, FS1.OTP, FS1.OTP, FS1.Axe, FS1.FaitSaillant, FS1.Utilisateur, FS2.DateInsertion  
         FROM FaitsSaillants AS FS1 INNER JOIN ( 
             SELECT Axe, Index, Max(FaitsSaillants.DateInsertion) AS DateInsertion, SUM(IIf(Axe = 'RAS', 1, 0)) As AxeCount  
             FROM FaitsSaillants 
             GROUP BY Axe, Index 
         ) AS FS2  
         ON (FS1.DateInsertion = FS2.DateInsertion  
         AND FS1.Index = FS2.Index)  
     )  AS FS3 ON Employes.CIP = FS3.Utilisateur) ON ControleAcces.Valeur = Employes.CIP
GROUP BY NomComplet, ControleAccess.Valeur;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FS3.Index` is NULL if there is no corresponding record, because of the LEFT JOIN. Wouldn't a test

```
IIf(IsNull(FS3.Index), ..., ...)
```

... be sufficient? I'm not sure so, since other conditions and joins are involved as well.

---

**UPDATE** (recaptulation of comments)

We can get the desired count (AxeCount) from the innermost nested SELECT (FS2):

```
SELECT
    Axe, Index, Max(FaitsSaillants.DateInsertion) AS DateInsertion,
    SUM(IIf(Axe = 'RAS', 1, 0)) As AxeCount
FROM FaitsSaillants  
...
```

This intermediate result must be passed to the outermost SELECT by including it in the select list of the intermediate SELECT (FS3):

```
SELECT FS2.AxeCount, FS1.Index, ...
```

The outer most SELECT has a GROUP BY clause. In this case, all fields of the select list must either be included in the GROUP BY clause or must be included in an aggregate function. The GROUP BY clause groups rows by the fields listed in this very clause. This usually reduces the number of rows, as several rows similar in their group fields are condensed to form one row. This means that the values of the remaining fields of the select list (not in the group fields) must be combined together. This is what the aggregate function does. Aggregate functions are

- Avg (average)
- Count
- First, Last
- Min, Max (minimum, maximum)
- StDev, StDevP (standard deviation)
- Sum
- Var, VarP (variance)

See [SQL Aggregate Functions (Access)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-aggregate-functions-HP001032172.aspx)

Now, we can add this in the outermost select list

```
IIf(SUM(FS2.AxeCount) > 0, ..., ...)
```

Comment: True, but the COUNT on FS3.Index is just there to show what I want to do. the real count I want to test is `SELECT COUNT(Index) FROM FaitsSaillants WHERE Axe = 'RAS' AND Utilisateur = FS1.Utilisateur`. This last condition is the problem.

Comment: Would a `SUM(IIf(Axe = 'RAS', 1, 0)) As AxeCount` in the inner most SELECT (FS2) get the right count?

Comment: Probably, but how could I get the value from the subquery? FS2.AxeCount doesn't work.

Comment: You have to put it in the select list of FS3 as well `SELECT FS2.AxeCount, FS1.Index, ...`

Comment: Since you have a GROUP BY you must use an aggregate function: `IIf(SUM(FS2.AxeCount) > 0, ..., ...)`

Comment: Well, it just works, thank you very much. Just edit your answer and I will accept it. Can you explain me why we need to SUM() here? How the GROUP BY interacts with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on exactly what you want to check in the FaitsSaillants table; you said:

> I would like it to check if there is any row in FaitsSaillants where
>   Axe = 'RAS'. If the Count() of this is > 0, then the condition is met.

But you also stated:

> something like SELECT COUNT(Index) FROM FaitsSaillants WHERE Axe =
>   'RAS' AND Employes.CIP = FS3.Utilisateur

My guess is that you meant `SELECT COUNT(Index) FROM FaitsSaillants WHERE Axe = 'RAS'`, because in the second SQL statement you're joining to two tables that aren't being referenced in the `FROM` clause of your subquery.

What about using `DCount` in your IIF statement?

```
IIF(DCount("Index", "FaitsSaillants", "Axe='RAS'"), '0 (RAS)', Count(FS3.Index))
```

This should work if you meant `SELECT COUNT(Index) FROM FaitsSaillants WHERE Axe = 'RAS'`, but it would need to be modified if you had something else in mind.

Just a caveat though: I would try to use the "domain" functions (DCount, DLookup, etc...) sparingly, because they are slow.

By the way, I believe you can also use a subquery in your IIF statement (is it giving you an error? It seems to work for me):

```
IIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FaitsSaillants WHERE Axe = 'RAS'), '0 (RAS)', Count(FS3.Index))
```

Just make sure you are putting the subquery in parenthesis.

Comment: The last part of your answer could work: I tried it and the syntax is accepted. However, I really need the `Utilisateur = FS1.Utilisateur`. Both FS1 and the subquery are searching in tb_SOMMAIRE and the `RAS` that I'm looking for is specific to the current user (`Utiliasteur`) that is treated. It obviously doesn't work when I add that condition; but how could I make a join and ensure we are on the same row that the same join on the main query? Added some details to my OP.

Comment: You can also try `IIf((select count(*) from FaitsSaillants where axe='RAS' and Utiliasteur=ControleAcces.Valeur),...`

Comment: same error, `ControleAcces.Valeur` isn't part of the aggregate function.

Comment: Didnt notice your 'group' clause... assuming Name is consistent with the Valeur field, change the second part of my above statement to `Utiliasteur=Max(ControleAcces.Valeur)`

Comment: ....Or add ControleAccess.Valeur to your GROUP clause (this is the right way if Name is not at a consistent level with Valeur)

Comment: Just tried it, now the error is different (my MS-Access is all in French as you might have noted, I'm doing my best to translate it): can't have an aggregate function into the WHERE clause. Probably because of the MAX. Also tried with ControleAccess.Valeur added to the GROUP clause and I'm back to the original error, the subquery can't find ControleAcces.Valeur

Comment: Lol.. yes I did notice; thats why i like this question. I took French in high school, though I dont remember much anymore as that was years ago. Are there different values of Valeur for each name?

Comment: I will probably add the structure of the tables to my post and some data too, it could help. All this structure have been developed by my predecessor. I'm new to MS-Access, the syntax isn't exactly the same as what I've learned from my SQL classes. And I must say that I've not played that much with SQL yet, when the query starts to be really complex, I'm stuck like now. I also think that there is room for improvement about the tables' structure but I have to deal with it. Unfortunately, I have to go for a meeting. To be continued tomorrow... and thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, posting the table structure might help, then we  can reproduce the query exactly. You're welcome, glad to try and help if possible.

Comment: It seems like Olivier's solution finally did the job. Yours would probably have worked out too. I guess there isn't always a "better" solution, not sure if it's faster to use SUM() or to do a complete different subquery.